# How to use expr inside regsub in TCL?

Tags: tcl, expr, regsub

Suppose, `set s1 "some4number"`

I want to change it to some5number.

I was hoping that this would work :

```
regsub {(\d)(\S+)} $s1 "[expr \\1 + 1]\\2"
```

But it errors out. What would be the ideal way to do this in TCL ?

Comment: I'm on my mobile right now so I can't answer properly, but "it is annoyingly complicated" is the summary. Unless you have Tcl 8.7 where I added a `-command` option to `regsub`, but that is still in check-out-of-source-control-only status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tcler's Wiki has many neat things. One of them is [this](https://wiki.tcl.tk/987#pagetocedb5a0e6):

```
# There are times when looking at this I think that the abyss is staring back
proc regsub-eval {re string cmd} {
    subst [regsub $re [string map {[ \\[ ] \\] $ \\$ \\ \\\\} $string] \[$cmd\]]
}
```

With that, we can do this:

```
set s1 "some4number"
# Note: RE changed to use forward lookahead
set s2 [regsub-eval {\d(?=\S+)} $s1 {expr & + 1}]
# ==> some5number
```

But this will become less awful in the future with 8.7 (in development). Here's what you'd do with an `apply`-term helper:

```
set s2 [regsub -command {(\d)(\S+)} $s1 {apply {{- 1 2} {
    return "[expr {$1 + 1}]$2"
}}}]
```

With a helper procedure instead:

```
proc incrValueHelper {- 1 2} {
    return "[expr {$1 + 1}]$2"
}
set s2 [regsub -command {(\d)(\S+)} $s1 incrValueHelper]
```